# Assigning a rvalue to a lvalue reference

Tags: c++

I was watching a tutorial about rvalues and lvalues and I got a little confused.

```
int& GetValue()
{
    static int value = 5;
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    int a = GetValue();

    GetValue() = 8;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << GetValue()  << std::endl;

    int b = GetValue();
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
5
8
8
```

I don't understand how `GetValue() = 8;` changes the value from 5 to 8. And now I always get 8 when you call `GetValue()`.

Comment: `GetValue() = 8;` modifies the value of `static int value` - is that the part you are struggling with?

Comment: Hint: All reference are lvalues.  Now, look at the return type of `GetValue`, what is it?

Comment: Can you explain what you expected and how it's different from what you observed? It's not clear which part is confusing you.

Comment: My guess as to what the confusion is would be along the lines of "Do you have to use ```static``` for ```value```? If so, why? Does it just override the function? Does ```value``` get declared every time you call it?" etc.

Comment: *"Assigning a rvalue to a lvalue reference"* It doesn't matter what you *assign* to it. When you *create* an lvalue reference, yes, you can only bind it to an lvalue. But anything you assign to it later is assigned to whatever the reference is bound to.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is a copy of the `static` variable in `GetValue()`:

```
int a = GetValue();
```

Therefore, the later assignment:

```
GetValue() = 8;
```

doesn't affect the value of `a`. It does, however, modify the value of the static variable, `value`, which is retrieved twice afterward:

- `std::cout << GetValue()  << std::endl;`
- `int b = GetValue();`

Comment: "modify the value of the static variable", but how?

Comment: @caraash `GetValue()` return type is `int&`, which is an *lvalue reference* bound to the static variable `value`. By assigning a value to that reference (e.g., `GetValue() = 8`), you are actually assigning that value to the static variable `value`. That is, the value returned by `GetValue()` "refers" to `value`.

Comment: @caraash This is similar to how the [subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) works in `std::vector<int>`: its `operator[]()` returns an `int&`. This allows you to modify the element of a vector by assigning to the value returned by `operator[]`, e.g., `vec[0] = 8`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `value` is first 5. Then you assign 8 to it.

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't understand how `GetValue() = 8;` change the value of `value`.

Comment: @caraash `GetValue()` returns a reference that refers to `value`.

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
int& GetValue()
{
    static int value = 5;
    return value;
}
```

is roughly equivalent to this...

```
static int value = 5;
int& GetValue()
{
    return value;
}
```

Except that in the first case, value is scoped to the function, so you cannot access it "globaly"(actually in the second one you can only access it within the same *translation unit*).

With your piece of code, both would print out `5 8 8`

---

This...

```
int& GetValue()
{
    static int value = 5;
    value = 2;
    return value;
}
```

is roughly equivalent to this...

```
static int value = 5;
int& GetValue()
{
    value = 2;
    return value;
}
```

and will return `2` every time.

Answer (score 0):

static keywork used in GetValue() function with value variable.
first when Getvalue is called on the top of main function, the variable value is created  on the head, this means that the value is not a local variable(stock in the function stack frame), so you can get it's reference (int& return a reference to value), the variable will be alive even the GetValue finishes.

second, int a = GetValue(); the GetValue will return a reference to static variable value.
the compiler will copy the contains of this reference to a variable. a is not a reference to static value, unless int& a is used.

third, GetValue()=8 return a reference to static variable value, then we asigned 8 to the return reference, so value is changed implicitly( one way to change a static variable )

finally, the static variable value is equal to 8, so GetValue() return 8 everytime you call it, unless you get a reference to static variable value, and change it.

this what explain, the serie of 8 in the ouput.